# Out of Stock Yes Custom Sort Issue on Category page

Tags: magento2

i installed custom extension for best seller sorting when i set display out of stock to No its works fine but when i set display out of stock Yes then its not working any idea its Magento2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

I think the best seller works on the best-selling product. It doesn't have any concerns with the out-of-stock or stock products.

If you share some code, then I will help more about this.

`Hint`! You see the configuration code, to debug check that links with the stock or out of stock

Comment: thanks for response actully i am upgrade my magento from 2.3.5 to 2.4.5 my extension works in old version fine i installed updated version of the extension but result was different but when i have google the issue i found a solution display out of stock set to no after that is works but i want display my out of stock product tooo

Comment: okay. Hope it will work fine.

Comment: no its not working i just explain the steps

Comment: can you come 1:1 chat in chat room

Comment: Can you please add me in the chat or tell me how we can add in the chat